# How many numerical multiplications for the product of three matrices?

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

For example you have the matrices $A, (5 \times 8), B, (8 \times 4), C (4 \times 10). $
The question wants you to find the number of multiplications if you were to multiply these matrices like $(A\times B)\times C$.

The answer is $5 \times 4 \times 8 + 5 \times 10 \times 4 = 160 + 200 = 360$ multiplications.

Comment: Could you clarify with what you need help with and what you have tried so far? It will make answers more helpful for you.

Comment: Yeah sure, so I initially thought that you would do (A * B) * C = (5 * 4) * C = (5 * 4) * (4 * 10), however that seems to give you the answer 5 * 10 which I can tell is wrong because 3 matrices wouldn't just give you 5 * 10.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/484661/calculating-the-number-of-operations-in-matrix-multiplication

Comment: The comment linked by RyanHowe counts operations and not just multiplications.

Comment: Yeah I've taken a look at that link already. I've looked everywhere for information or examples on this topic, can't seem to find much online for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start this step-by-step. How many multiplications do you need if you were to multiply $M (1\times 8)$ by $N (8 \times 2)$?

$M$ has one row of $8$ numbers. When we multiply that by the first column, that's $8$ multiplications, which are then added up. (It's very similar to a dot product). Then, when we multiply the second column, that's another $8$ multiplications. That's a total of $16$ numerical multiplications.

What about if we use your $A, (5 \times 8), B, (8 \times 4)$ and multiply $A\times B$? For the first row, we do $4 \times 8 = 32$ multiplications. And we do that for all $5$ rows, so the total number of multiplications is $5\times 4 \times 8 = 160$.

How about $D (5 \times 4), C (4 \times 10)$ and multiply $D \times C$? The same reasoning leads us to $5\times 4 \times 10 = 200$ multiplications.

In fact, if we let $D = A\times B$, and we added the number of multiplications, we would get $(A \times B) \times C$ takes $360$ numerical multiplications to compute.

Comment: It seems a simple way to look at it is to multiply both of the unique numbers by the number that resides in the row of the first matrix and the column of the second matrix.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an $5$ by $8$ matrix $A$ and you multiply it by an $8$ by $4$ matrix $B$ you will arrive at a $5$ by $4$ matrix and each entry in this matrix $AB$ will require you to multiply 8 times. Hence computing $AB$ requires $5\times 4\times 8$ multiplications.

Can you handle the rest?

Let's look at a smaller case. Say we are multiplying a $2\times3$ by $ 3\times 2 $. This should result in a $2 \times 2$ matrix. But how many times will I have multiplied?

$$\Big(\matrix{1 & 2 & 3 \\ 10& 20 & 30} \Big)\Bigg( \matrix{2 & 3 \\ 5 & 7 \\ 11 & 13} \Bigg) $$

$$= \Big( \matrix{1\times 2+2\times 5+3\times 11 & 1\times 3 +2\times 7+3\times 13 \\ 10\times 2+20\times 5+30\times 11 & 10\times 3 +20\times 7+30\times 13 \\} \Big) $$

$$= \Big( \matrix{45 & 56 \\ 450 & 560 \\} \Big) $$

So each entry (and there are $4$ because it's a $2 \times 2$ matrix) took $3$ multiplications (Where did the $3$ come from in the problem?). That means we had $12$ multiplications altogether. If you really think through why this number has to be 12 you can put together what has to happen in the larger case.

Comment: So you wouldn't do (A * B) * C = (5 * 4) * C = (5 * 4) * (4 * 10)? Yeah the AB part makes sense. Ill think over the C part.

Comment: @LukeD No, that wouldn't give you the right answer of 360.

Comment: So basically, you take the first multiplication which is 5 * 4, then multiply it by 8 and that's only for A B. So for C, I'm assuming you do something similar, but since it has the 10 which is not common for A and B you would multiply 5 * 4 by 10 in order to find AB * C. There for 5 x 4 x 10 = AB * C and 5 x 4 x 8 = AB.

Comment: @LukeD. I would look at smaller examples and count how many times you have to do a multiplication problem. Then look at the bigger case. What happens in $2 \times 3$ times $3 \times 2$ case?

Comment: Ok thanks for the help/suggestions. Ill practice right now.

Answer (score 1):

For a matrix mutiplication of order $(m\times n)$ and $(n\times p)$.

No of mutiplications involved are $= m\cdot n\cdot p$.

No Of additions involved are $= m\cdot n\cdot (p-1)$

so here for

first mutiplication: $5\cdot 8\cdot 4= 160$

Second mutiplication: $5\cdot 4\cdot 10 = 200$

Total $= 360$

Similarly Total addition would be $=300.$

Comment: Number of additions will be $m \cdot (n -1 ) \cdot p$